# Can't find Article with id=... error, but article is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to delete `@article`, I am getting this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#destroy, Couldn't find Article with id=1...` But when I go back on Index page, `@article` is deleted.

What should I do?

Destroy method:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy
  redirect_to 'root'
end
```

Link for delete(`/show.html.erb`):

```
<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete %>
```

If you need more files, I will upload them..

Comment: try using `redirect to :root if @article.destroy`

Comment: Do you have any after_delete callbacks in your Article model?

Comment: This worked: redirect_to :root if @article.destroy .. Thanks bhanua1

Comment: @bhanua1, maybe you should post it as answer for future reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like @bhanua1 say

> try using `redirect to :root if @article.destroy`

Comment: This is not a very fair answer, is it now?

Comment: Yes, but it should be @bhanua1 the one to post it for having provided the right answer... Pasting someone else's comment should not be rewarded in S.O.

Comment: I post the answer as `community wiki` I do not receive any reward. Is only to have a resolved question. If I am wrong sorry, flag me and a moderator will take over as appropriate

Comment: You should give time to the one answering to gain the credit. Since you put is as community wiki, leave it like this. But if bhanua1 answers, you should then remove it...

Comment: Not to make a big deal, but yea this is some sort of courtesy, we give the commenter a chance to claim his answer.

Comment: @bhanua1 have to change the acepted answer to delete this.

Comment: Startsp has to change the accepted answer, but he may not come back here since he got what he was looking for. That's why you have to wait and give bhanua1 a chance to post his answer.

Comment: oo my mistake @Startsp instead bhanua1. if I had not written the answer, this would be a question unresolved. When Startp change the correct answer I dont have problem to delete this. I only want to help

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
redirect_to :root if @article.destroy
```

Comment: I am relatively new to rails. `@article.destroy` returns the @article object itself even if the record is completely deleted from the database. so the `if` statement at the end is  evaluated to `true` and proper redirection will takes place. @Mischa

Comment: Apparently this works, but if I don't think the error has anything to do with the redirection. So I don't understand why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid errors when hitting the destroy action for a record that is already deleted you could use the following:

```
def destroy
  if article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
    article.destroy
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

`find_by` returns `nil` if it doesn't find the record while `find` throws an exception. `nil` is considered 'falsey' by ruby which will bypass the body of the `if` when the record is not found.

It is also best to use a path helper to avoid having 'magic' strings in your code that you have to remember to update if you decide to change your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Just change a little in the **redirect_to** line

```rb
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to :action => :index #this will redirect to article index page if delete action was successful
end
```